# Paypal user authentication in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I have integrated paypal mobile checkout library in my iOS application and I am able to do transaction in sandbox environment but I want first seller/merchant to login to my application using paypal access like the images below.

[image]

I have referred many links for the same .But not getting any idea.
Please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Here are some links:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/getting-to-know-paypal-access

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2528-how-to-use-paypals-mobile-express-checkout-library-for-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is "GetVerifiedStatus" api provided by paypal which is used to check whether user is having correct paypal email address .I have solved it using the link below:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getverifiedstatus-api-operation